# Run a Python script from another background Python script

Tags: python, subprocess, runtime-error, updates

I am trying to make an updater. I have made the main program call a file `updater.py`, which runs hidden as I do not want to disturb the execution of the main program.

The `updater.py` file then checks if an update is available by connecting to a GitHub repository, and accessing a `.txt` file inside it, and checks if the `__version__` identifier of the main program is less than the latest version. If yes, then the program calls `installer.py`, which needs to be a visible process to interact with the user.

In `main.py`, I have written the following line:

```py
Popen([sys.executable, 'updater.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) # Start the updater
```

This works as expected and `updater.py` runs in the background.

In `updater.py`, I have written:

```py
Popen([sys.executable, 'installer.py', latestVersion], stdin=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.STDOUT, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

But this does not run `installer.py`. It instead gives the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Updated\updater.py", line 18, in <module>
    Popen([executable, 'installer.py', latestVersion], stdin=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.STDOUT, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 992, in __init__
    errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1361, in _get_handles
    p2cread = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(stdin)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

I don't know what the problem and it would be really helpful if anyone knows something.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In *updater.py* you have:

```py
Popen([sys.executable, 'installer.py', latestVersion], stdin=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.STDOUT, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

This should be:

```py
Popen([sys.executable, 'installer.py', latestVersion], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

**Update**

If you want the user to be able to communicate with *installer.py* via the console, then you may not want to be specifying `stdin=subprocess.PIPE`, which would expect "console input" for *installer.py* to be specified programmatically in *updater.py*. Anyway, if you want the code to run visibly (it appears you are using Windows), then try:

```py
Popen(
    [
        'cmd',
        '/C',
        sys.executable,
        'installer.py',
        latestVersion
    ],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    shell=True
)
```

Comment: Thank you. But even then the expected output is not achieved. I need the `installer.py` shell to be visible to the user as it involves input and output. I doubt that the `installer.py` script is even running even though it is called by `Popen()`. Thanks.

Comment: See update to the answer.

Comment: I decided I'll use `subprocess.run()`. But then still when `updater.py` is called from `main.py`, `installer.py` isn't still showing up the window (`installer.py` runs as I tested a file operation just for checking). I'm sorry if it is a stupid question. Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to update your question with the latest code, which needs to be more complete. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Post three simple but complete versions of *main.py*, *updater.py* and *installer.py* where *installer.py* runs but without a window, which I can copy and paste and run with no changes and duplicate your problem. Then post a new comment here so I know when you have done that.